# Sum of elements of a matrix (list), but only at indexes given in another matrix (list)

Tags: python, list, matrix, sum

I have some matrix containing integers:

```
matrix = [[85, 61, 48, 100, 96],
 [23, 72, 13, 45, 36],
 [97, 80, 65, 84, 46],
 [80, 59, 76, 61, 99]]
```

and a matrix containing:

```
index = [[-1, 0, 0, -1, -1],
 [0, -1, 0, -1, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, 0],
 [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1]]
```

I want to sum all the elements of matrix, where the element in index is equal to -1, but I can't use any package.
The expected output should be 935.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
res = sum(v for ii, val in zip(index, matrix) for i, v in zip(ii, val) if i == -1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
935
```

As an alternative:

```
res = 0
for ii, val in zip(index, matrix):
    for i, v in zip(ii, val):
        if i == -1:
            res += v
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the itertools to flatten the matrix and zip it along the indices::

```
import itertools as it
sum([v for (i, v) in zip(it.chain.from_iterable(index), it.chain.from_iterable(matrix)) if i == -1])
```